# How can I check if a file is beeing edited (locked ?) using csom?

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am using sharepoint CSOM to download / upload file from a OneDriveBusiness account.

Before downloading the file I need to check if the file is currently in use.
File.CheckOutType is alway "None".
I though using File.LockedByUser property, using the following code, but I got a ServerObjectNullReferenceException when the file is not locked.

```
var listItem = clientDocs.GetItemById(item.Id);
clientContext.Load(listItem.File.LockedByUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var locked = listItem.File.LockedByUser.UserId;


I was hoping to be able to do do something like : 
if (file."locked")
{
  throw exception...

}

enter code here
```

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

[File.LockedByUser property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.lockedbyuser.aspx) is a *deferred* property, it need to be requested explicitly as demonstrated below:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
ctx.Load(listItem, i => i.File.CheckOutType, i => i.File.CheckedOutByUser, i => i.File.LockedByUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if(listItem.File.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None) //Is checked out?
{
     var checkoutUserName = listItem.File.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName;
     var lockedUserName = listItem.File.LockedByUser.LoginName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Is it possible that the File.CheckOutType is always none when the file is open on a the Ipad with excel ? I will do more test, but at first sight editing the file with excel doesn't change the CheckOutType.